# How can I pass '#' as part of a parameter in html?

Tags: html

I have an html form that I desire to be pre-populated with variables that are passed as parameters within the URL. Basically imagine that I am typing this string directly into the browser.

When I pass a variable that contains '#' however, it is read as syntax different from the string and the full variable is not copied into the form.

Example: https://form.domain.com/formname??variable1=www.variabledomain.com/#/h7Y6F53/

When I enter this into my browser, **variable1** pre-populates only with "www.variabledomain.com/". I'd like it to pre-populate with "www.variabledomain.com/#/h7Y6F53/".

What can I do differently?

Cheers

Comment: Do you need to url encode it?

Comment: Yes, you need to url-encode it.

Comment: Got it. So the url-encoding for '#' is %23, yes?